# What is "<<-" operator called in ruby,

Tags: ruby

I was reading a book about ruby. Then i saw that code.

```
code = <<-code
if val == true:
    print "...."
code

print code
```

I was confused about that first but then i looked closely. So it's just assigning that code to a variable . I did googled it but found nothing.

so What is that "<<-string" operator called in ruby.

Comment: And it's odd that "GOD" wouldn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) operator in ruby.

[Indent modifier](http://log.gmarik.info/2007/12/rubys-here-document-heredoc-mini.html)

By default HereDoc terminator is expected to be placed on the very beginning of the separate line
By using `-` on HereDoc declaration, you may indent end terminator arbitrary:

```
greeting = <<-"here document ends"
                 Hello world
               here document ends
```

Keep in mind that leading spaces are kept.

Answer (score 0):

This is “here document” or “heredoc”.

From the documentation:
If you are writing a large block of text you may use a “here document” or “heredoc”:

```
expected_result = <<HEREDOC
This would contain specially formatted text.

That might span many lines
HEREDOC
```

The heredoc starts on the line following <

You may use any identifier with a heredoc, but all-uppercase identifiers are typically used.

You may indent the ending identifier if you place a “-” after <<:

```
  expected_result = <<-INDENTED_HEREDOC
This would contain specially formatted text.

That might span many lines
  INDENTED_HEREDOC
```

for More info, please refer to [HereDoc @ ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents)